# Xamarin Android Binding of Razorpay 1.6.26 (AAR) giving error

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, aar

I am making Xamarin Android Binding library of Razorpay 1.6.26 using AAR (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/razorpay/checkout/1.6.26/checkout-1.6.26.aar) but its giving error due to a parameter type in OnRequestPermissionsResult method, which is declared as

```
OnRequestPermissionsResult (int p0, string[] p1, int[] p2)
```

but it should be

```
OnRequestPermissionsResult (int p0, string[] p1, Permission[] p2)
```

I am trying to change through Metadata.xml using following attr code

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.razorpay']/class[@name='CheckoutActivity']/method[@name='OnRequestPermissionsResult' and count(parameter)=3 and parameter[1][@type='int'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String[]'] and parameter[3][@type='int[]']]/parameter[3]" name="type">Android.Content.PM.Permission[]</attr>
```

But its not working and error is as same as earlier

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0115  'CheckoutActivity.OnRequestPermissionsResult(int, string[], int[])': no 
suitable method found to override   RazorPayBindingNew
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test the binding, and it seems there is something wrong in your Metadata.xml. You can try the following code:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.razorpay']/class[@name='CheckoutActivity']/method[@name='onRequestPermissionsResult' and count(parameter)=3 and parameter[1][@type='int'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String[]'] and parameter[3][@type='int[]']]/parameter[3]" name="type">Android.Content.PM.Permission[]</attr>
```

And sorry for my mistake. The `name="type"` is right. The `name="manageType"` should be used to change return type.

And the `'OnRequestPermissionsResult'` should be `'onRequestPermissionsResult'`. I have checked the binding errors, the error message showed the name should be `onRequestPermissionsResult`. I have tested it, the error message disappeared when I changed it to `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

Comment: Not working, still same error.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0115 'CheckoutActivity.OnRequestPermissionsResult(int, string[], int[])': no suitable method found to override RazorPayBindingNew ...\RazorPayBindingNew\RazorPayBindingNew\RazorPayBindingNew\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Razorpay.CheckoutActivity.cs 272 Active

Comment: Can the project build successfully, if you delete the `attr` tag in the meatadata.xml? @seopower

Comment: No build fails with above error posted in previous comment. You can try with this AAR from Razorpay - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/razorpay/checkout/1.6.26/checkout-1.6.26.aar

Comment: Did you check the link in the answer's update part? @seopower

Comment: When I set the Binding Library's target framework as Android 5.0, the error message disappeared. @seopower

Comment: Yes I copied ATTR syntax from that link but no effect and the person claiming it worked, has not posted its code. Also Android 5 wont work as normally we target aur App min Android 6 and Compile with Android 11 or 12

Comment: Sorry for my late replay. You can check the answer. I have fixed the error. @seopower